# What is the :> operator?

Tags: ocaml

I was looking through the [Dream](https://github.com/aantron/dream) source code when I stumbled upon an operator (probably defined in a package) that I have never seen before:

```ml
let method_ =
  match (method_ :> Method.method_ option) with
  | None -> `GET
  | Some method_ -> method_
```

What is the `:>` operator, where does it come from, what does it do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:>` is a builtin operator in the typing sub-language that asserts a subtyping relation. So it's not from a package.

In this particular case it is saying that `method_`, which probably has some more specific type, should be treated as if it is of type `Method.method_ option`. The type checker will first verify that the type of `method_` is a subtype of the specified type.

This is documented in [Chapter 9, Section 7.7](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/4.14/htmlman/expr.html#ss:expr-coercions) of the OCaml manual, where the construct is called a "coercion".